# oracle Jet - populating basic table with json

Tags: html, knockout.js, oracle-jet

**update**

I believe I've found the error. I changed up the JSON-data and found that I've managed to add a "," on the last HeaderText-row in the HTML. Removed it and now it's pushing the data properly into the table..

I'm trying to populate a table with some JSON-data, but all I'm getting is this error:

```
Uncaught Error: oj-table with id 'table1': Unable to parse columns='[
            {headerText: "ID", field: "id"},
            {headerText: "Name", field: "name"},
            {headerText: "Username", field: "username"},
            {headerText: "E-mail", field: "email"},
            ]' for OJ-TABLE with id table1 to a JSON Object. Check the value for correct JSON syntax, e.g. double quoted strings. SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in JSON at position 19
at Object._throwError (ojcustomelement.js:514)
at _coerceVal (ojcustomelement.js:1110)
at Object.oj.BaseCustomElementBridge.__ParseAttrValue (ojcustomelement.js:1124)
at Object.oj.BaseCustomElementBridge.__InitProperties (ojcustomelement.js:1028)
at Object.InitializeElement (ojcomponentcore.js:5504)
at Object._connected (ojcustomelement.js:378)
at HTMLElement._connectedCallback [as connectedCallback] (ojcustomelement.js:404)
at Object.setDomNodeChildren (knockout-3.4.2.debug.js:288)
at Object.setDomNodeChildren (knockout-3.4.2.debug.js:2827)
at Object.oj.CompositeTemplateRenderer.renderTemplate (ojcomposite-knockout.js:105)
```

I'm using https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users as my JSON-source.
I want to push the data into the specified columns. What am I missing? What I've found on Google looks very similar to my code, and the documentation hasn't helped me much.

I'd like to point out that I'm a complete newbie to JET and I haven't worked much with JSON-data prior.

My code looks like following

HTML

```
<oj-table id='table1' aria-label='testTable'
  data='[[dataSource]]'
  columns='[
            {headerText: "ID", field: "id"},
            {headerText: "Name", field: "name"},
            {headerText: "Username", field: "username"},
            {headerText: "E-mail", field: "email"},
            ]'
  style='width: 50%;'>
```

JS

```
define(
['ojs/ojcore', 'knockout', 'jquery', 'ojs/ojtable', 'ojs/ojarraytabledatasource'], 
function (oj, ko, $) {
    function testTable() {
        var self = this;          
        self.data = ko.observableArray();
        $.getJSON("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").
            then(function (users) {
                $.each(users, function() {
                    self.data.push({
                        id: this.id,
                        name: this.name,
                        username: this.username,
                        email: this.email
                    });
                });
            });
        self.dataSource = new oj.ArrayTableDataSource(
            self.data,
            {idAttribute: 'id'}
        );
    }             
        return testTable;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty straightforward and hopefully this small change should be enough: In your HTML column definition use double quotes for the keys as well, not just the values.

```
<oj-table id='table1' aria-label='testTable'
  data='[[dataSource]]'
  columns='[
        {"headerText": "ID", "field": "id"},
        {"headerText": "Name", "field": "name"},
        {"headerText": "Username", "field": "username"},
        {"headerText": "E-mail", "field": "email"},
        ]'
  style='width: 50%;'>
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this was not the solution to my issue. I've created the app through the ojet-cli and created the component with it too if that matters.

Comment: I got the same error as prior, and not because your code was faulty but because of the "," I had managed to sneak in at the end of the source.

Answer (score 0):

You put and extra coma(,) on the last row declaration besides that you should add double quotes for the keys...

```
<oj-table id='table1' aria-label='testTable'
  data='[[dataSource]]'
  columns='[
        {"headerText": "ID", "field": "id"},
        {"headerText": "Name", "field": "name"},
        {"headerText": "Username", "field": "username"},
        {"headerText": "E-mail", "field": "email"}
        ]'
  style='width: 50%;'>
```

This should work...